# How/Where Do I Begin?

Tags: planets, worldbuilding-process

I've got an endless stream of ideas in my head, I'm just not sure how to begin organizing them all. I've got multiple universes brewing in my mind of various genres, and I'm just clueless as to what comes first. How should I go about getting a start in worldbuilding and fleshing out a world?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding Brandon! This is likely considered off-topic the main site but would definitely be accepted on [meta], the place where we ask about the site itself as well as the worldbuilding process. Please view the [tour], [help], and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Hello Brandon. I think this question will not be well received here because it is too broad, and based mainly on opinions. I used to have the same problem about putting ideas into paper as you do, so my advice is: write down whatever is on your mind. Just write. Put your thoughts on paper (or computer file). Write like there was no tomorrow and your afterlife depended on it. Neil Gaiman said a newbie writer should write at least two thousand words a day. Then you can start throwing out what you end up seeing you don't like, and focus on the aspects of your worlds that you do like.

Comment: This question would appear to be more appropriate in the [Writers Stack](https://writing.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is not about world building, it is about the act of writing. https://Writing.Stackexchange.com would be a much better place. Just some general advice, if you want to be a writer, you have to write. Start putting down words. Write every day. If new ideas come up write them down.

Comment: @AndyD273 Brandon never said he wanted to write. He said he wanted to worldbuild - I don't think it's relevant what for.

Comment: @Liquid That's fair, and a good point.This still isn't about worldbuilding. Your answer is a good place for them to start.

Comment: Hi Brandon,  I'm not really sure what you're asking.  Worldbuilding is about the creation of systems.  Part of your question implies difficulties with writing things down (which WB is not equipped to help with.)  If you're trying to flesh out a particular world system, then I'd ask about that system.  There's also no *One True Way* to go about designing a world system.  Everyone does it different.

Comment: Also, should your question be put on hold, it's not a bad thing.  It just means that you've got an opportunity to edit your question to make it a better fit for WB.  I hope you do clarify what you're asking for.  Your question has the tone of someone frustrated with their inability to make progress and I can empathize with that.

Comment: @AndyD273 I see; still maybe the question could be edited to make it more fit for Worldbuilding meta, as Anonymous suggested?

Comment: @Liquid Yes, I think that would be a good solution actually. I voted for that.

Comment: To back up @Renan: the difference between a genius and a pauper is often a pencil and a piece of paper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First and foremost:

**Take note of your ideas.**

It doesn't matter whether you do that on paper or on your personal computer. The point with ideas is that they are vague until you write them down, and 
you're bound to forget them in time.

If you write them down, you'll be able to add pieces of information as you go, making simple ideas more and more sketched out and complex as time passes.

**Choose a "core"**

You ought to pick a core concept to work on. Regardless of what you are building (a novel? A videogame?) you can't use *everything* that comes to mind.

In traditional fantasy novels, let's say, it's more likely to find elves than aliens. This doens't mean that you can't write about fantasy aliens: if it's a core concept you can work with that and make it believable.

If you are daring, confident and capable enough, you can mix up nicely two or three "big" ideas and sculpt them to work together.

**See what else could be relevant**

After you've decided the focus points of your world, see whatever ideas could add flavor to it without ruining the mix. If you're writing about an high fantasy setting, with mages, dwarves, elves and all the usual suspects, probably isn't a great idea adding aliens. Unless you're a genius, that is.

See what ideas from your list could apply and what would not. In the end, it's up to your taste; don't be afraid to experiment something unusual for your genre, just try not overdo it. 
Once you'll start working on a setting, you won't be able to fit all your ideas into it. Just take note of them for later use.

**Worldbuild away**

So, at this point you should have a couple of major "traits" for your world and a bunch of less characterizing ideas. Now you can properly worldbuild - filling the gaps of how all this works together. 
Imho, of course.

Comment: All very good advice. I'd like to add a comment about "Once I do these things, where does this website come into play?" We're here to help with the filing of the gaps, once you've started to identify what they are. And feel free to come visit with us in chat, which is a lot less formal, and where it's easier to brainstorm ideas in a way that wouldn't work as a question.